# Linq to SQL - SubmitChanges function

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Documentation says, SubmitChanges updates only changed values.

My question is what exactly that means ?
Let's say a simple example:

```
row.Variable = 5;   ( row.Variable contained 4 before change )
```

This is clear to me. It will update. What about this ?

```
row.Variable = 5;   ( row.Variable contained 5 before change )
```

Well, will it update as I changed it to same value or It knows it's same and it will not update ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SubmitChanges updates only **changed** values.

(*emphasis mine*)

If there isn't any change, it I suppose it will not update as it is overkill to do *nothing*.

So, it will only update if the value is different from what is already stored. If not, then it is bad design.

Comment: Well, I thought they are some setters/getters for the Variable and I thought when this Setter function is called, It can be interpreted as change.

Answer (score 1):

SubmitChanges will update the values that is deference from the stored one.
You can checkout this function that give you the answare:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();

... //do some thing

var changeSet = db.GetChangesSet();
var updatesCount = changeSet.Updates.Count;
```

That will be show you the changes count (if any).